# why does a nonempty convex set have a nonempty interior

Tags: analysis

Suppose $A \neq \emptyset$ is a convex set in $R^n$, or generally a metric space, then is there any neat proof to show that $A$ has nonempty interior? Thanks for the help.

Comment: what if $A=[0,1] \times \{ 0 \} \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: Suppose $A$ is a point. Is $A$ convex? What is the interior?

Comment: Not true. Take a point - it is also a convex set. Ok, less trivial - a line in the plane has zero interior since it fits no open disc.

Comment: What about a closed segment in x-y plane?

Comment: Perhaps you mean the so called _relative_ interior. Think of a triangle in $\mathbb R^3 \dots$